# cordova admob pro not displaying banner

Tags: cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

I am using Cordova 6.3.1, when I use cordova-plugin-admobpro, I am getting error, AdMob not defined. I have tried many codes and suggestions but it's still not working. Please help me on these.

I am building app in only android and build is always successful, just only it's just banners are not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

few things you need to check before you add the banner id etc.

- Make AutoShow: true
- Make AdId to PublisherId
- Check the testing mode and banner id is entered correct
- Make sure that your android sdk has installed google play services
- Make sure that your android sdk is up to date

These are commond problems in such kind of situtations. you can check and test it. It would be working then.